# How to get a docker image on a digitalocean droplet to have https?

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, https, digital-ocean

I have a REST API written in python which I have dockerized. I'm using nextJS for the frontend which requires that my API calls are to https urls (I would want https anyways). I already have my droplet setup with a domain and I have gotten my API to work without having https. From what I've read I need to incorporate nginx in order to get https. I am able to make my domain point to either nginx or my API. How do I set it up so that my REST API somehow incorporates nginx so that I can get https?

Comment: You can use nginx as a reverse proxy. So you can have nginx getting the https requests and forwarding them to your REST API. https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Comment: This link doesn't mention anything about using a docker container which is why I'm having trouble doing this.

Comment: Using a docker container only means, you proxy pass to the container name and port, like `proxy_pass container_name:8000;` thats basically it. But I can provide you a much more detailed example as answer.

Comment: I would appreciate that very much.

Answer (score 2):

So you have your docker container with your REST API running on a port, that is exposed outside the container, I take `8000` as example and `rest_api` as docker container name.

Because you already use docker, I would recommend setting up nginx with docker too. At first you need to create an internal network for the containers to communicate. `docker network create web` should do this job. Then you need a `docker-compose.yml` similar to the following to setup nginx:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/var/log/nginx # folder to write logs in
      - ./sites-enabled:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro # all enabled sites .conf files
      - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt:ro # configuration files by certbot (keys)
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot:ro # webroot for certbot check
    ports: # open ports on host
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks: # attach container to an internal network
      - web

networks:
  web:
    external: true # web network gets declared outside of this file and should not be created with docker compose up
```

Now you need to start your `rest_api` container. It's important, that you add the container to the web network too, so it can be found by the nginx container. It's also important to expose the port to internal networks and not to the host. So as example `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  rest_api:
    image: myimage
    container_name: rest_api
    expose: # expose only exposes the port to internal networks, ports would expose the ports to the host
      - 8000 # exposes port 8000 to internal connected networks
    networks:
      - web

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

Then you only need to configure your nginx settings. So you create a `mysite.conf` file inside the `sites-enabled` directory. That file could look somehow like the following:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.com;   # your domain name

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://rest_api:8000;   # needs to be http://<container_name>:<port_number>
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;   # all headers are optional, but help the applications getting information about the original request
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {   # this part would be for certbot certificate requests
    root /var/www/certbot;
  }
}
```

That as quick but detailed walkthrough. Let me know if it helped or you have more questions.

Comment: Does this not answer your question? Just saw you removed that. Anything not working?